# Handling field information and authentication in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions

The issue which I have discovered is how would you handle for example UserA is tied to GroupA with an option only available to GroupA.

How would I be able to make that UserA will see that information and UserB can't on the same page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/47mub.png - I had to link the image due to reputation issues.

The diagram shows a little example of what I'm trying to do so that if UserA is tied to GroupA they would see the diagram above but if I was UserB they wouldn't see the "Join Game" option.

I apologize if the title is incorrect for the point i'm trying to get across.

Comment: Is *UserB* connected to *GroupA* too?

Comment: UserB is seperate from GroupA and has no relation to GroupA sorry forgot to put that in simple case it was so UserA could access the field but UserB can't

Comment: Why you just check if the user have *GroupA*?

Comment: That would have to be wrapped around the entire table like a SQL query which is the thing i'm not sure how to do hence the question